# How do I position a div relative to the mouse pointer using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Suppose I have one link in my page and I want that when I place my mouse just over the link, a div will show there according to mouse x,y.

How can I accomplish this using jQuery?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15494357/want-to-show-div-just-under-the-link-using-jquery-when-user-click-on-link

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15635270/weird-behaviour-of-drop-down-menu-created-by-jquery

Answer (score 88, accepted):

```
var mouseX;
var mouseY;
$(document).mousemove( function(e) {
   mouseX = e.pageX; 
   mouseY = e.pageY;
});  
$(".classForHoverEffect").mouseover(function(){
  $('#DivToShow').css({'top':mouseY,'left':mouseX}).fadeIn('slow');
});
```

the function above will make the DIV appear over the link wherever that may be on the page. It will fade in slowly when the link is hovered. You could also use .hover() instead. From there the DIV will stay, so if you would like the DIV to disappear when the mouse moves away, then,

```
$(".classForHoverEffect").mouseout(function(){
  $('#DivToShow').fadeOut('slow');
});
```

If you DIV is already positioned, you can simply use

```
$('.classForHoverEffect').hover(function(){
  $('#DivToShow').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Also, keep in mind, your DIV style needs to be set to `display:none;` in order for it to fadeIn or show.

Comment: k, kinda messed that up, not exactly sure what your trying to achieve here, but you can get the coordinates of the mouse with the first function mousemove, it will store it in the variable mouseX and mouseY, you can then add or subtract the distance that you want to achieve from those variables, if that makes any sense.

Comment: sure thing, if you need anything specified or some more help, just post up here in the comments.

Comment: also make sure you set the position of #DivToShow to 'absolute'

Comment: Better to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`.

Comment: How about using the pageX and pageY directly on the mouseover function?

Comment: Below code display div at fixed position, not matching the mouse pointer position


<div class="flyout hidden">
</div>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#tblGrid').on('mouseover', 'a', function (e) {
            var mouseX = e.pageX;
            var mouseY = e.pageY;
            $(".flyout").append($(this).attr('title'));
            $('.flyout').css({ 'top': mouseY, 'left': mouseX }).fadeIn('slow');
        });

        $('#tblGrid').on('mouseout', 'a', function (e) {
            $(".flyout").empty();
            $('.flyout').hide();
        });
    });

Answer (score 10):

There are plenty of examples of using JQuery to retrieve the mouse coordinates, but none fixed my issue.

The Body of my webpage is 1000 pixels wide, and I centre it in the middle of the user's browser window.

```
body {
    position:absolute;
    width:1000px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left:-500px;
}
```

Now, in my JavaScript code, when the user right-clicked on my page, I wanted a div to appear at the mouse position.

Problem is, just using **e.pageX** value wasn't quite right.  It'd work fine if I resized my browser window to be about 1000 pixels wide.  Then, the pop div *would* appear at the correct position.

But if increased the size of my browser window to, say, 1200 pixels wide, then the div would appear about *100 pixels to the right* of where the user had clicked.

The solution is to combine **e.pageX** with the bounding rectangle of the body element.  When the user changes the size of their browser window, the "**left**" value of body element changes, and we need to take this into account:

```
// Temporary variables to hold the mouse x and y position
var tempX = 0;
var tempY = 0;

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
        var bodyOffsets = document.body.getBoundingClientRect();
        tempX = e.pageX - bodyOffsets.left;
        tempY = e.pageY;
    });
})
```

Phew.  That took me a while to fix !  I hope this is useful to other developers !

Comment: It is... Trying to do the exact same thing, but I was having trouble. Thanks! +1

Comment: To correct for a vertical offset like `top: 50%;
    margin-top: 500px;
`, also use `tempY = e.pageY - bodyOffsets.bottom;`. But that won't work if there are no top or margin-top properties on the body.

Answer (score 7):

You don not need to create a `$(document).mousemove( function(e) {})` to handle mouse x,y. Get the event in the `$.hover` function and from there it is possible to get x and y positions of the mouse. See the code below:

```
$('foo').hover(function(e){
    var pos = [e.pageX-150,e.pageY];
    $('foo1').dialog( "option", "position", pos );
    $('foo1').dialog('open');
},function(){
    $('foo1').dialog('close');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

  var cX = 0;
  var cY = 0;
  var rX = 0;
  var rY = 0;

  function UpdateCursorPosition(e) {
    cX = e.pageX;
    cY = e.pageY;
  }

  function UpdateCursorPositionDocAll(e) {
    cX = event.clientX;
    cY = event.clientY;
  }
  if (document.all) {
    document.onmousemove = UpdateCursorPositionDocAll;
  } else {
    document.onmousemove = UpdateCursorPosition;
  }

  function AssignPosition(d) {
    if (self.pageYOffset) {
      rX = self.pageXOffset;
      rY = self.pageYOffset;
    } else if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop) {
      rX = document.documentElement.scrollLeft;
      rY = document.documentElement.scrollTop;
    } else if (document.body) {
      rX = document.body.scrollLeft;
      rY = document.body.scrollTop;
    }
    if (document.all) {
      cX += rX;
      cY += rY;
    }
    d.style.left = (cX + 10) + "px";
    d.style.top = (cY + 10) + "px";
  }

  function HideContent(d) {
    if (d.length < 1) {
      return;
    }
    document.getElementById(d).style.display = "none";
  }

  function ShowContent(d) {
    if (d.length < 1) {
      return;
    }
    var dd = document.getElementById(d);
    AssignPosition(dd);
    dd.style.display = "block";
  }

  function ReverseContentDisplay(d) {
    if (d.length < 1) {
      return;
    }
    var dd = document.getElementById(d);
    AssignPosition(dd);
    if (dd.style.display == "none") {
      dd.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      dd.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
  //-->
</script>


<a onmouseover="ShowContent('uniquename3'); return true;" onmouseout="HideContent('uniquename3'); return true;" href="javascript:ShowContent('uniquename3')">
[show on mouseover, hide on mouseout]
</a>
<div id="uniquename3" style="display:none;
position:absolute;
border-style: solid;
background-color: white;
padding: 5px;">
  Content goes here.
</div>
```