# Show popup near user highlight

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an Chrome extension and I want to show popup/menu near the user text selection,

I saw this question:
[How do I position a div relative to the mouse pointer using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666367/how-do-i-position-a-div-relative-to-the-mouse-pointer-using-jquery)

But it doesn't seems to work, or at least doesn't seems to work for extensions.

How can I do that?