# Tooltip moving with cursor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oB9a6.png)

```css
ul#listcontainer .li1 {
  display: block;
  width: 210px;
  height: 130px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
.li1 span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 140px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: 220px;
  padding: 2px 0;
  background-color: #000;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.65);
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity .5s ease-in-out;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 14px;
}
.li1:hover span {
  opacity: 1;
}
.li1:hover span:hover {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

```html
<ul id="listcontainer">
  <li class="li1">
    <img src="images/li1.png"><span><b>Exteriors:</b> <br>Minimal Wear, Battle Scarred<br><br><img src="images/tick.png"><br>&nbsp;</span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hello everyone. So I made a tooltip showing after I hover the box with red border. The thing I want is that when I hover over the div with red border - the tooltip begin to moving/following with the mouse. Tried to search how to do it but I didn't found answer. I think it will be some jQuery code... I let you guys tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Could you define "following" the mouse?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4666367/how-do-i-position-a-div-relative-to-the-mouse-pointer-using-jquery

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this code and no need to change the css as shown in this http://jsfiddle.net/bo113jxu/8/ :

```
$('.li1').mousemove(function (e) {
    $('span', this).css({left: e.pageX - 100, top: e.pageY + 10});
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

The `position:absolute` will work good as long as there's only one `.li1` element, but in case we have more `.li1` elements we'd face a problem shown in this **[jsfiddle demo1](http://jsfiddle.net/bo113jxu/61/)**; TO fix this the `position` of `.li1` *should* be set to `fixed` [**jsfiddle demo2**](http://jsfiddle.net/bo113jxu/66/).. just like what [@ViktorMaksimov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5469248/viktor-maksimov) <sup>kudos</sup> said in his answer which I was wrong about it.

Answer (score 2):

CSS code:

```
.li1 span {
  position: fixed;
  margin-left: -110px;
}
```

jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('.li1').mousemove(function( event ) {
   $(this).find('span').css({    //Position the tooltip
    'left' : event.pageX + 'px', //Left position - the X position of the mouse
    "top" : (event.pageY + 20) + 'px' //Top position - the Y position of the mouse 
   });
 });
});
```

Firstly the tooltip should be positioned fixed.
When you are moving the mouse inside the `<li>` element the tooltip will have left position - the position on X of the mouse to the window, and top position the position on Y of the mouse + 20, because the tooltip not to be exactly next to the mouse, because if you move your mouse fast enough the tooltip will hide.
And we are setting margin-left to the tooltip - negative value half of its width to make the tooltip centered to the mouse.

Comment: doesn't need to be `fixed`, it works with `absolute` too

Comment: you're right it should be `position:fixed` to avoid this behaivor if you have more than one `.li1` item [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bo113jxu/61/) .. upvoted